On mod $p$ constructions related to determinant
Given an $m\times m$ matrix $M\in\mathbb Z^{m\times m}$ and a prime $p$, is it possible to construct in $Logspace$ another matrix $t_1(M)$ whose determinant is guaranteed to be determinant $Det(t_1(M))=Det(M)\bmod p$ where $Det(t_1(M))\in[0,p-1]$?

We know Determinant is in $L^2$ and so this is doable in $L^2$ but we require computation of determinant of $M$ first. So perhaps this is doable in $L$ if we can avoid direct computation of determinant of $M$.

What if Determinant mod $p$ is bound by $(\lg p)^c$ at a fixed $c\geq0$?

I misunderstood your question, sry (I thought you meant "with the same determinant mod p as det(M) mod p). I see now what you want is an integer matrix whose integer determinant is the unique number in [0,p-1] that is congruent to det(M) modulo p. That seems interesting and more complicated.
